# Whats the name of this pattern and is frowned upon?

Tags: java, design-patterns

In Java, I see a lot of libraries lately that have classes with methods that always return the instance of the class so you can can call multiple methods without needing separate lines of code. For example:

```
public class Resource{

  public Resource path(String path)
      //execute some code
      return this;
  }
```

So you can do things like this

```
new Resource.path("1").path("2").path("3")
```

Rather than the verbose:

`public void path(String path)`

```
Resource r = new Resource();
r.path("1");
r.path("2");
r.path("3");
```

Is there a name to this pattern and is it good/bad practice?

Comment: It's used for method chaining..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's called fluent interface pattern.

Often applied in builder pattern aka fluent builder.

http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html

As to second part of the question:

Pros:

1. Code readability and conciseness - it reflects what the code really
   does, like DSL

Cons:

1. Problems with debuging
2. Problems wih logging
3. The command query separation mentioned in the link above gets broken

For more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

The are probably some more aspects I didn't cover though

Comment: +1, Will be good if you cover the second part of OP question. :)

Comment: I'd call this an example of method chaining, but not necessarily a fluent interface. Note this quote from the Martin Fowler article you linked: "I've also noticed a common misconception - many people seem to equate fluent interfaces with Method Chaining. Certainly chaining is a common technique to use with fluent interfaces, but true fluency is much more than that."

Comment: Yeah, you are right, these 2 terms are definitely closely related, for me, "more than that" means that in addition to returning "this", you also have more natural language describing, e.g the building precess, as opposed to e.g new A().setB().setC()